# Setting a custom property with DontEnum

Tags: javascript, properties, dontenum

If I create:

```
Object.prototype.count = function() {};
var m = {prop: 1};

for(var i in m)
    window.status += i + ", ";
```

in the code above `i` contains also `count` inherited by its prototype. Now I want
to know if there is a way to set a custom property as the flag DontEnum (it is not settable for custom property) so it will not be enumerated.

I know I can do `if(m.hasOwnProperty(i))` to check only its property but if I
write a sort of array's API I should say to a programmer to remember that... and
this is not acceptable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the Object object has a property 'propertyIsEnumerable', but it's not very usefull. Maybe http://dhtmlkitchen.com/learn/js/enumeration/dontenum.jsp can give you more insight? If you follow the chapters, you'll end up on a page with a simple question "How to set the DontEnum attribute", answered even more simple and pretty disappointing: "You can't." Luckily there are more chapters. You should end up on a page containing an interesting phrase: "OK, ok, IE is crap, JavaScript sucks, blah, blah... time to stop complaing and roll my sleeves up.".
Bottom line of the tutorial though: "*Enumerability in JavaScript creates a serious problem*."

Answer (score 3):

Since JavaScript 1.8.5 you can use the Object method [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty (object, propertyName, attributes);
```

Where `attributes` is a map in which you can set various attributes such as `value`, `enumerable` and `writable`. If the property exists it is modified, otherwise it is created.

Juriy Zaytsev built an [ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) in which you can find the browsers supporting `defineProperty` (and many other functions), although he left out that Safari doesn't support `defineProperty` for DOM objects - just the contrary of IE!!! :( -

### EDIT

Juriy updated the table.